# How do I insert data from my JS function into table after clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table showing results of different variables in my javascript function. I'd like the table to appear after clicking the submit button (which I've managed to do with the *onclick* function). However my problem is actually getting the data into the table. I am unsure how to reference the variables to specific cells in the table. I realise that this explanation might be a bit difficult to understand so I've got an example below:

I want to reference and do calculations with this information:

```
function myFunction() {

  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var favoritenumber = document.getElementById("favoritenumber").value;
  var birthdayyear = document.getElementById("birthdayyear").checked;

  var a1 = +(age - 10);
  var fn = +(favoritenumber * 2);    
  var by;
        if (document.getElementById("birthdayyear").checked) {
            by = +14; 
            } else {
            by = 0;
            }

  var total = +(a1 + fn + by);

  document.getElementById("submit").innerhtml = total;
  }
```

And show the 'total' in a separate paragraph (say, a h1 tag) *onclick* of the submit button:

```
                                     This is the TOTAL
```

And the rest of the information to be inserted below into a bordered table with the following headings:

```
A1           FN            BY
```

But for example, if 'birthdayyear' is not checked, this column does not show.

**How do I reference the data in myFunction to insert it into the table?**

My calculations are more complicated than this but they work, it's just the referencing I need help with!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the suite of functions associated with `insertRow()` [here at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp). I think I understood your question correctly, but let me know if I didn't. Try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {



var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var favoritenumber = document.getElementById("favoritenumber").value;
  var birthdayyear = document.getElementById("birthdayyear").checked;

  var a1 = +(age - 10);
  var fn = +(favoritenumber * 2);    
  var by;
  if (document.getElementById("birthdayyear").checked) {
      by = +14; 
  } else {
      by = 0;
  }

  var total = +(a1 + fn + by);

  var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);

  var cella1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellfn = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellby = row.insertCell(2);

  cella1.innerHTML = a1;
  cellfn.innerHTML = fn;
  cellby.innerHTML = by;

  document.getElementById("submit").innerhtml = total;
  }
```